# NoMethodError: undefined method `scan' while running a helper test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a helper that truncates a user's full-name to only show their first name.  I wrote a little test to just be sure that it works. I'm forcing myself to learn to test rigorously early on, so this may be overkill but I'm trying to learn a bit more about testing various aspects of the application.

**application_helper.rb**

```
 module ApplicationHelper

    def truncate_username(user)
        @first_name = user.scan(/\A[a-zA-Z]+/).first
        return @first_name
    end
end
```

**application_helper_test.rb**
require 'test_helper'

```
class ApplicationHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase

  setup do
    @usr = users(:travis)
  end

  test "First name should be truncated" do
   assert_equal "Travis", truncate_username(@usr)
  end
end
```

Every time I try to run this test I get a NoMethodError:

```
ERROR["test_First_name_should_be_truncated", ApplicationHelperTest, 0.7588860000250861]
 test_First_name_should_be_truncated#ApplicationHelperTest (0.76s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `scan' for #<User:0x007f9dcec71af0>
            app/helpers/application_helper.rb:4:in `truncate_username'
            test/helpers/application_helper_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:ApplicationHelperTest>'
```

Any ideas on why this is not working?  Or perhaps how I could implement this test better.

Comment: You are passing in a User object which doesn’t respond to scan. Does User have a full name accessor you meant to call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scan` is a [String](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) method.  You are passing your method a `User` object, which does not have a `scan` method (unless you define one).

To make it clearer, your method will work if you pass it a string. In this case, that's the user's full name.

```
def truncate_username(full_name)
    @first_name = full_name.scan(/\A[a-zA-Z]+/).first
    return @first_name
end
```

You could also consider putting this method directly on the `User` model.  If you define it something like

```
User.rb

def first_name
   full_name.scan(/\A[a-zA-Z]+/).first
end

(replace full_name with whatever attribute you are storing the user's name to)
```

you could then instead be calling `@user.first_name` in your application instead of `truncate_username(@user.full_name)`.

Comment: Thanks for that. Quite simple really.  Do you feel like putting the method in the model is a better practice?  At the moment I'm not using this function for much except the header to say "welcome Firstname".

Comment: Sure thing.  I, personally, would put it in the model, since you're using it specifically with a `User` model.  Readability-wise it also makes more sense to me to see `@user.first_name` in my view.